# laravel 5.8 Auth::user null after verified authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I've upgraded a laravel 5.4 to 5.8 project and added in some vue files vs blades and noticed that at some point along the way Auth::user() started to return null.

I reset all Auth files to laravel default from a fresh project, still returns null. I checked config files for auth and session variables per other post suggestions, no resolution. I can successfully Log::debug out that the AuthenticatesUsers.php 'authenticated' method logs out the Auth::user() successfully. When I move to another route from /login, i.e /browse, logging out Auth::user() immediately returns null.

I've php artisan cleared cache, config, and routes, run composer dump-autoload. My User model has all necessary traits and the DB uses 'id' as primary key. I can't figure out why I'm losing authentication immediately after logging in.

web.php:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/browse', 'ListingController@index')->name('listings');
});
```

problematic controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    Log::debug(Auth::user());

    $criteria = $request->get('criteria');
    $data = $request->get('page') ?? ['page' => 1];

    $allCriteria = [];

    if($criteria) {
        //pluck all criteria values in a method and put into searchable buckets based on prefix
        $allCriteria = $this->getSearchCriteria($criteria);
    }

    $listings = $this->listingService->get(array_merge($allCriteria, $data));

    return $this->showListings($listings, $data, $criteria, 'Listings');
}
```

Comment: Are your routes protected with the web Middleware?

Comment: @mdexp i just updated question with web.php -- i did not have this wrapped before but even after adding it, Auth::user still logs out null

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly wrote `web` instead of `auth`, it should be the `auth` middleware. Otherwise you can try to force the Auth facade to pickup the user with`Auth::guard('web')->user();`

Comment: @CaddyDZ im using stock laravel + vue Auth package and question states I can't access Auth::user() from controllers outside of login. Its a pretty clear question and there's not a lot of code outside of route that should be necessary here.

Comment: Where are you using `Auth::user()`? Can you reproduce this problem in a fresh Laravel install with just the routes you mentioned in the question?

Comment: A question is not clear if I can't copy the code and see the error in my computer

Comment: the controller method with the Auth:: call has been added above. if i navigate to /browse directly after /login, this logs out null